# Haskell mapTree implementation using foldTree

Tags: dictionary, haskell, tree, typeerror

This code is from an assignment I already solved. Still I am trying to figure out if I could fix my initial attempt.

So we got this tree structure and the foldTree function.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
 | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)

foldTree :: (b -> b -> b) -> (a -> b) ->  Tree a -> b
foldTree op f (Leaf x)  = f x
foldTree op f (Node l r) = foldTree op f l `op` foldTree op f r
```

Now mapTree has to be implemented using foldTree.
I got it done this way.

```
 mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
 mapTree' f tree = foldTree Node (Leaf . f) tree
```

What I initially came up with and still don't get to work is this:

```
 mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
 mapTree f tree = foldTree Node transFunc tree 
   where transFunc :: Tree a -> Tree b
         transFunc (Leaf x)    = Leaf (f x)
         transFunc (Node l r)  = Node (transFunc l) (transFunc r)
```

Comment: Your initial implementation should be modified to `mapTree f tree = transFunc tree`

Comment: It doesn't work besides not using foldTree :/

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answers you're looking for. You've already given the most reasonable implementation that uses `foldTree`.

Comment: @4castle, perhaps the OP wants to understand what went wrong?

Comment: If you compare your 2 implementations, or just look at the type signature of `foldTree`, you'll see that your `transFunc` should have type signature `a -> Tree b`. You should be able to figure that out from the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The second function is wrong because of its type: `Tree a -> Tree b` while `foldTree` expects it to be `a -> b` where `a` is taken from `Tree a`. `b` is required by `mapTree` to be `Tree b` therefore the third argument to `foldTree` should be of type `a -> Tree b`.

So the simplest fixed version of your `transFunc` is:

```
mapTree :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree f tree = foldTree Node transFunc tree 
  where transFunc :: a -> Tree b
        transFunc x = Leaf (f x)
```

Note that you need to enable `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to compile it.

And that version of `transFunc` is an equivalent of your working solution: `(Leaf . f)`